# pfsense 2.0 traffic priority - set full priority for single host

Tags: networking, bandwidth, qos, pfsense, traffic-shaping

I have a network with several computers all on the same network and since I have very limited bandwidth I would like to prioritize traffic almost like a CPU scheduler prioritize processes.

Example: Computer A: Used for webstuff: YouTube, downloads, news, emails etc. Computer B: Transferring files over HTTP Computer C: Transferring files over ftp, rsync whatever

What I would like to do is to give A up to for example 90% of the available bandwidth IF A requires it. The leftovers (10%) is divided between B and C (5% each if both is busy) If A is not utilizing all bandwidth then of course B and C should share the full bandwidth (50% each as long as both are maxing out their bandwidth).

All computers are on the same network (192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1-10 for example).

Appreciate if anyone could shed some light on how I should set up my network to achieve this. To be honest I actually need a step by step guide on how I should set this up.

Network setup: (ADSL modem configured in bridge mode (1500kbps/300kbps))

[ADSL modem (bridge)]<->[pfsense2.0]<->[switch]<->[Computer A,B,C...etc]

Comment: From your tags I can see that you have already found out about QoS, which is a router-side setting. How to use it is highly dependent upon your exact router model and the exact operating systems on computers A,B and C. To get a useful answer to your question, better add that info to your post.

Comment: harrymc: I fail to understand why this is relevant if for example computer A and B both are downloading a huge file on port 80 or 81 for example. I want to make sure A always is prioritized. I'll add the info if you wish but could you please take the time to explain to me why this kind of info is relevant in this situation?

Comment: This is to know if the router can do QoS and how. The OS of the computers involved might also have an impact on what is possible to do.

Comment: Speedtouch WL750 ADSL bridge mode, Pfsense 2.0, Windows XP and several Debian Squeeze installations.

Comment: I can only find Speedtouch TCW750. Is that it ? If you have a link towards its manual, please add it.

Comment: Sorry - a little typo. It is a 780WL. It is however set to bridge mode as you might have noticed so I do not understand what the ADSL modem can do other than forward the traffic to pfsense 2.0 where all the magic is done. Regardless the manual is here : http://rory.allford.net/wp-content/uploads/2007/03/st-780wl_cli.pdf

Answer (score -2):

The 780WL is very complex, but its QoS does not seem to do the job. Its firmware is encrypted and so protected against installation of a more evolved firmware such as DD-WRT or OpenWRT that can do priorities. Therefore the solution is not here.

On the other side, pfSense does seem to support QoS. It has the concept of Traffic Shaping, described in the [Traffic Shaping Guide](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Traffic_Shaping_Guide). This allows you to setup rules, called "limiters", that can guarantee bandwidth. Limiters are setup by creating them under "Firewall > Traffic Shaper", on the Limiters tab.

Limiter rules seem to be based principally on the source address or the destination address (IP). This will probably force you to discard the DHCP and assign static IP addresses to the computers, to be able to use these addresses in the rules.

Not having your environment, I cannot supply a step by step guide. However, the documentation seems useful and contains useful links at the end. For points that remain unclear you could either google or search in the [pfSense Forums](http://forum.pfsense.org/) or post there your own questions.

Comment: I already have static ip's for all my systems. I am also aware of the traffic shaper and the limiters. I have also posted a question (or two) at pfsense forums without getting a answer to my specific questions. On IRC people also claims that pfsense can be configured to do what I ask for but no one seems to be willing (or able) to explain how. This is exactly the reason my question is labeled pfsense 2.0 traffic priority. Thanks for your efforts anyway.

Comment: I am afraid that you will have to find out how to use pfSense by yourself, maybe by examining the source code and even fixing the bugs (that's open source for you). Just a suggestion: To simplify your life it might be worth-while replacing router+pfSense+switch by one new router (in that case choose one on which DD-WRT can be *easily* installed).

Comment: I would like to note here that the [pfSense Traffic Shaping Guide](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Traffic_Shaping_Guide) is not a "guide" at all, but rather a page of definitions, some of which have been copied from Wikipedia.  Which is why so many people are reaching out for help on this topic.  See [https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php/topic,26782.0.html](https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php/topic,26782.0.html)