# traffic sharing on pfsense2

Tags: networking, pfsense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pfsense 2.0 traffic priority - set full priority for single host](https://superuser.com/questions/290327/pfsense-2-0-traffic-priority-set-full-priority-for-single-host)

I have a network with several computers all on the same network and since I have very limited bandwidth I would like to prioritize traffic almost like a CPU scheduler prioritize processes.

Example: Computer A: Used for webstuff: youtube, downloads, news, emails etc. Computer B: Transfering files over http Computer C: Transfering files over ftp, rsync whatever

What I would like to do is to give A up to for example 90% of the available bandwidth IF A requires it. The leftovers (10%) is divided between B and C (5% each if both is busy) If A is not utilizing all bandwidth then of course B and C should share the full bandwidth (50% each as long as both are maxing out their bandwidth).

All computers are on the same network (192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1-10 for example).

Appreciate if anyone could shed some light on how I should set up my network to achieve this. To be honest I actually need a step by step guide on how I should set this up.